# AIR application and fast search engine

Tags: sqlite, air

I'm working on a AIR desktop client which will basically be used to search for pictures. For now, the search will only be performed on the picture filename, but I'd like to add a tagging system. 
I would like the search to be very fast, but I'm not sure SQLite is responsive and fast enought.

Do you have any alternatives to store and retrieve datas locally within a AIR application ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is very fast.  On typical (small-scale) usage, it's faster than most other databases.  When we switched to SQLite we found a 4x performance gain on our typical queries with our real schema and a production data set.

Besides, in AIR, you don't have many options.  Anything you implement directly in AS3 or integrate with via the new native process integration (which requires launching a separate process and communicating via std i/o) would be MUCH slower.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, the fact that SQLite does not provide foreign keys and such does not make it slower?

If I have a "picture" table (with id, name, path and collection) and a "tag" one (with picture_id, name), I'd like my query to be very responsive...